# Rails - display results of index and show actions via ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a very simple Post resource with two actions, *index and show*. My template contains a sidebar with links to each previous post. I want the sidebar links to display their content (i.e. *the results of the "show" action*) via ajax

I know there are lots of [excellent](http://www.alfajango.com/blog/rails-3-remote-links-and-forms/) [tuts](http://stjhimy.com/posts/7-creating-a-100-ajax-crud-using-rails-3-and-unobtrusive-javascript) that show you how to create a form that submits with ajax but this time I want to use it to display the contents of my index and show actions without page referesh

. Are there any decent tutorials out there that give tips on how to do this?

I reckon I need to create a **show.js.erb** file, and tell my index action to respond to js but I'm a little bit stuck getting any further. I don't quite know what to put in controller's show action or show.js.erb - it's a little difficult to visualise what I need to do

PS - using rails 3.0.7, jquery-1.5

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Got this working, it was very simple in the end.

**Step 1** - add `:remote => true` to links in sidebar

```
#application.html.haml
%nav#sidebar
  - for post in @posts
    = link_to post.title, post_path, :remote => true
%div#main
    = yield
```

**Step 2** - tell your controller to respond to JS on the show action

```
def show
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  @posts=Post.all # needed for sidebar, probably better to use a cell for this
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # show.html.erb
    format.js # show.js.erb
  end
end
```

**Step 3** - Create _post.html.haml

```
# _post.html.haml
%article.post
  = sanitize post.body
```

**Step 4** - Create **show.js.erb** and replace the html in the #main div with the contents of the _post partial (that we created in step 3)

```
# show.js.erb
$("#main").html("<%= escape_javascript(render @post) %>");
```

Now all the content is passed via ajax and it's working fine.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a full answer at hand, because I'm relatively new to this, too.

But, I would start by taking a look at JQuery's `get()` method. You should be able to use that to call the index or show method. Those methods should return the html that you want to display in the non-sidebar section of the page. You can use `get()`'s callback handler to place that HTML into the appropriate div on the page.

Sorry that this is a little vague, but if you play with this I bet you'll figure it out.

Comment: it's an interesting idea - I am fairly sure there is a server side alernative to this client side approach - for SEO purposes and also because I want to cache on the server - still, I will have a look at this and see what I can find - thanks