# How would I make the page jump to top after an AJAX load in ROR?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I understand that the following js should jump the browser to the top of page,

```
$('html').scrollTop(0);
```

But where would I put this code so that after an ajax load it would be activated?

I have a `show.js.erb` file that contains the js for the asynchronous load, but simply putting that js in there doesn't work, I imagine because it would be happening simultaneously as the load.

```
$("#tag_posts").html("<%= escape_javascript(render @atag) %>");
```

So, how would I do this?

Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="generator" content="Bootply" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="//html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
    <!-- Google Fonts -->
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bree+Serif' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    </head>
    <body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="box">
      <div class="column col-sm-12 col-xs-12" id="main">

            <!-- main right col -->
            <div class="column col-sm-9 col-xs-11" id="main">

                <div class="padding">
                    <div class="full col-sm-9">

                        <!-- content -->                      
                        <div class="row">

                         <!-- main col left --> 
                         <div class="col-sm-12">

                              <!-- Render Tag Posts Asynchronously to Populate Stream -->
                              <div id="tag_posts"></div>

                              <!-- Render Posts Partial to Populate Stream -->
                              <%= render "posts/index" %>
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you are building your Ajax request object?

Comment: Added, truncated/edited for brevity

Comment: I wanted to see your JAVASCRIPT which is building the AJAX object. Or if you are using jQuery, I would like see $.ajax() statement.

Comment: That line of js is it. The rest is ruby.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nut sure you need it to happen for each Ajax call, but if you do you can use the [ajaxComplete](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/). It will be trrigerd every time an Ajax call will complete.

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
    $('html').scrollTop(0);
});
```

If you don't want to trigger it for each call, you can add a condition to the function:

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function( event, xhr, settings ) {
    if ( settings.url === "<%= escape_javascript(render @atag) %>" ) {
        $('html').scrollTop(0);
    }
});
```

Check the link if you need more useful examples.

Comment: I think the simple 'html' selector might not be working because only a part of the page scrolls which I'm trying to get to the top. Do you know the syntax for targeting scrolling to the top of a specific div? Thanks!

Comment: If you need to scroll to the top of a specific element, just use its id. for <div id="myDiv"></div> - you can use: $("#myDiv").scrollTop(0)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have it executed for all AJAX calls in your document you need something like this:

```
$(document).on("ajax:success", "form[data-remote]", function(e, data, status, xhr) {
  $('html').scrollTop(0);
});
```

In the example above when a form element with a data attribute called `data-remote` sends an AJAX call and the call succeeds the function is executed. Read more about `on` [here](https://api.jquery.com/on/).

Another example from [jQuery Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/) but  this time with `ajaxSuccess`:

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function() {
  $( ".log" ).text( "Triggered ajaxSuccess handler." );
});
```

Yet another example from the docs but this time with appending the callback directly to the [`ajax`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function:

```
var jqxhr = $.ajax( "example.php" )
.done(function() {
  alert( "success" );
})
.fail(function() {
  alert( "error" );
})
.always(function() {
  alert( "complete" );
});
```

Comment: What if there's no form? ie. it's loading from the db

Comment: @Laser see the docs. The selector (`form[data-remote]` in this case) is optional! That means either you can just leave it!

Comment: @Laser btw. How do you mean loading AJAX from DB?

Comment: I think the issue may be that jquery isn't working inside a jquery function. For testing the js working, $(document).ajaxSuccess(function() {
  $( ".log" ).text( "Triggered ajaxSuccess handler." );
});  doesn't log anything to the console, but standard js inside the jquery $(document).ajaxSuccess(function() {
  console.log( "Triggered ajaxSuccess handler." );
});  works fine. Any ideas?

Comment: Why should something like `$(".log")` work? why not just `console.log`?

Comment: Your example used `$(".log")` so I thought that was a thing?

Comment: No my example is just an exact copy of what is shown in jquery documentation. Sorry. My bad!

Comment: Strangely, even giving all the links an `:onclick => "location.href='#posts_top'"` changes the url visually and loads the content, but even with a `<a name="#posts_top"></a>` above where the posts load, the page doesn't move to the place.

Comment: test something like `$(document).ajaxSuccess(function() {
  alert('it worked');
});` to see if it works. I am still not sure if you load your data over AJAX.

Comment: Yep, that worked. I know it works because new posts appear at the top of the page when I scroll up. I just don't want to have to manually scroll up to view those new posts.

Comment: try `window.scrollTo(0,0);` it's pure JS and it will rule out that jquery is not working inside jquery theory!

Comment: Cool, so jquery isn't the issue I don't think, cause that didn't work either.

Comment: Can't cause ruby's interaction? I think I'm going to make a new question for this more basic onclick/anchor issue that makes no sense to me, and by finding the solution to that the solution to this will become clear.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28268449/why-doesnt-page-anchor-work-in-ruby-on-rails

Comment: Dude! That is not called AJAX.

Comment: Ajax is happening simultaneously on click, so I'm considering a possible interaction.

Comment: neither in your new post, nor here I see no signs of an AJAX call. I am starting to think that the problem is there!

Comment: From the question `$("#tag_posts").html("<%= escape_javascript(render @atag) %>");` I believe that is the totality of the ajax call in ROR, as the content asynchronously loads fine.

Comment: That is not AJAX, that is just asset pipeline rendering the `@atag` into your JS.

Comment: What would an ajax call look like?

Comment: `$.ajax({...})` or `$.get({...})` or even `$.post({...})`

Comment: Perhaps I'm not evening using ajax. I didn't know, can you do asynchronous loading without ajax in ror?

Comment: You need to review some basics man. Wikipedia is your friend! I'm outta here!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6038281/rails-display-results-of-index-and-show-actions-via-ajax

Comment: See that `remote: true` thats the magic. See [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html)

Comment: Ah, thanks. So this would just be referred to as asynchronous loading with built-in rails helpers? It's very confusing because it says Ajax in the context of loading content 25 times on that page. I see now that I'm not making any direct js call to ajax, so thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, please ask a question after you have read the rails guide, asked google and found nothing on SO and/or wikipedia.

Comment: Everything in the rails guide and SO seems to infer ajax.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I tried exactly all the ways mentioned above. none solved it.
The problem was that I had included some  tag in the file which returned the ajax response. I removed the styles from there and it doesn't jump now.