# Why Doesn't Page Anchor Work in Ruby On Rails?

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

So I have links that have an href value to load ajax and an onclick value to link to the top of the page. When I click the links both the ajax content loads and the url show a reference to the anchor, but the page doesn't move to the anchor.

I've tried anchors in both the `show.html.erb` and `index.html.erb` which visually show up where they should be for test when I scroll to the top, but the page doesn't move to that location. Any ideas what could be causing this?

`show.html.erb` and `index.html.erb`

```
<a name="#posts_top">love and kittens</a>
```

On click the following happens visually to the url in the browser:

```
http://localhost:3000 => http://localhost:3000/#posts_top
```

Yet, the content loads and the page only jumps slightly to accommodate for the new content, but doesn't move the the anchor.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the attribute `href` to point to another anchor (which may defined either by the `name` or `id` attribute.

For example:

```
<h3><a name="menu">Menu</a></h3>
<ul>
<li><a href="#a001">Jump to a001</a></li>
<li><a href="#a002">Jump to a002</a></li>
<li><a href="#a003">Jump to a003</a></li>
</ul>

<h3><a name="a001">a001</a></h3>
<p>paragraph text ...</p>

<h3><a name="a002">a002</a></h3>
<p>paragraph text ...</p>

<h3><a name="a003">a003</a></h3>
<p>paragraph text ...</p>

<hr>

<p><a href="#menu">Jump to Menu</a></p>
```

To note, you can also use `id` instead of `name` like so...

```
<a href="#a001">Jump to a001</a>

...

<h3 id="a001">a001</h3>
```

Read more about it [here](http://www.tagindex.net/html/link/a_name.html)

Comment: Thanks JTG! Your initial answer that you deleted was perfectly succinct so that I understood, but thanks for elaborating. Maybe just add back to your answer that it's a syntax error.