# Unnecessary request to server for link_to anchor on same page in rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

[This question's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28268449/why-doesnt-page-anchor-work-in-ruby-on-rails) implementation is not working for me in rails 5.  In rails 5, It properly jumps to the anchor tag, but I notice in the logs that it is making a fresh request.

I do not want to make a request to the server because there is a form on the page whose data gets lost.  I only want to jump to a certain part of the page.

Code:

```
<h1 name="top-page">Blogs</h1>

...

<%= link_to "Back to Top", anchor: "top-page" %>
```

Perhaps this issue is related to turbo links?

Answer (score 1):

This is a [bug of turbolinks](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks/issues/105). You can disable turbolinks in your link for fixing full-page request:

```
<%= link_to "Back to Top", anchor: "top-page", data: { turbolinks: false } %>
```

Comment: Unfortunately the request to the server is still occurring with this implementation.

Comment: Do you have something like this in html `<a data-turbolinks="false" href="#top-page">Back to Top</a>` ?